# Grouped data from CSV and create chart with R

Tags: r, csv, graph, charts, bar-chart

Well, with R. 
I have this CSV:

```
"ID","Kind","Variety","Category","Kgrs","Kgrs_m2"
"120-1","HOLLAND","MULHACEN","12G",1206,0.25
"120-1","HOLLAND","MULHACEN","12M",4708,0.99
"120-2","HOLLAND","MULHACEN","12G",2190,0.46
"120-2","HOLLAND","MULHACEN","12P",5746,1.20
"120-3","CHERRY","MINISTAR","A",9165,3.05
"120-3","CHERRY","MINISTAR","B",50,0.017
"120-3","CHERRY","MINISTAR","DES",1182,0.39
"120-3","HOLLAND","MULHACEN","12G",372,0.12
"120-7","CHERRY","MINISTAR","A",6584,3.05
"120-7","CHERRY","MINISTAR","B",321,1.05
```

I want to do something like this graph, with R:

[image]

I read the CSV, but I don't know what I must do to group data from the CSV and put this data into the barplot.

Also I need add Variety to each group of ID.

This is my code:

```
path <- "./"

cosechas <- read.csv(paste(path, "test.csv",  sep="/"),header=T)

cosechas$Kgms <-  as.numeric(cosechas$Kgms)



fi <- c(cosechas$Kgms)
names(fi) <- levels(cosechas$Category)


png(paste(path, "cosechas.png", sep="/"))

barplot(fi, ylab="Kg", xlab="Categoria")
dev.off()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wasn't [any of the previous answers about grouped barplots](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+grouped+barplot) helpful? If you have specific problems, [please show the code you have tried and describe why it didn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Cheers.

Comment: Ok! sorry. My code. Edited

Comment: Now! sorry, the code. Im newbie with R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the "fill" to "group" if you want it all monochrome.

```
df <- read.csv('your/file.csv')
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = ID, y = Kgrs, fill = Category)) + 
geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position='dodge')
```

Comment: What about if I put the Variety for each ID to?

Comment: Check out the `interaction` function (`?interaction`).  You might want `x = interaction(ID, Variety)`.